# rsync through multiple ssh hops

Tags: ssh, rsync

I connect to a machine via a command I do not fully understand (the `-J`):

```
dargaud@local $ ssh -J ext-user@hop.example.com,user@gateway user@destination
user@destination $ ls
```

Now I would like to transfer some files from this machine to another not open to the outside. I know you can wrap ssh commands in the `rsync` call with `RSYNC_CONNECT_PROG` or `-e`

What is the correct connection syntax for my rsync ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out right as I was posting the message:

```
$ rsync -nCavz -e "ssh -J ext-user@hop.example.com,user@gateway user@destination" user@destination:/DirSource/ /DirDest/
```